# Find Image in GridView, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an Image inside a GridView. I need to make the path for it and want to do it in the back code (C#). I can't find gvImage though. Do I use GridView1.FindControl or something?

I want to find it in C#

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Competitor_ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowEditButton="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Competitor_ID" HeaderText="Competitor_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Competitor_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Competitor_Salutation" HeaderText="Competitor_Salutation" SortExpression="Competitor_Salutation" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Competitor_Name" HeaderText="Competitor_Name" SortExpression="Competitor_Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Competitor_DoB" HeaderText="Competitor_DoB" SortExpression="Competitor_DoB" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Competitor_Email" HeaderText="Competitor_Email" SortExpression="Competitor_Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Competitor_Description" HeaderText="Competitor_Description" SortExpression="Competitor_Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Competitor_Country" HeaderText="Competitor_Country" SortExpression="Competitor_Country" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Competitor_Gender" HeaderText="Competitor_Gender" SortExpression="Competitor_Gender" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Competitor_ContactNo" HeaderText="Competitor_ContactNo" SortExpression="Competitor_ContactNo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Competitor_Website" HeaderText="Competitor_Website" SortExpression="Competitor_Website" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Competitor_Photo" HeaderText="Competitor_Photo" SortExpression="Competitor_Photo" /> 
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="gvImage" runat="server" Height="122px" Width="148px" />   
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>       
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/UserDatabase.accdb" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM `Competitors` WHERE `Competitor_ID` = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO `Competitors` (`Competitor_ID`, `Competitor_Salutation`, `Competitor_Name`, `Competitor_DoB`, `Competitor_Email`, `Competitor_Description`, `Competitor_Country`, `Competitor_Gender`, `Competitor_ContactNo`, `Competitor_Website`, `Competitor_Photo`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" SelectCommand="SELECT `Competitor_ID`, `Competitor_Salutation`, `Competitor_Name`, `Competitor_DoB`, `Competitor_Email`, `Competitor_Description`, `Competitor_Country`, `Competitor_Gender`, `Competitor_ContactNo`, `Competitor_Website`, `Competitor_Photo` FROM `Competitors`" UpdateCommand="UPDATE `Competitors` SET `Competitor_Salutation` = ?, `Competitor_Name` = ?, `Competitor_DoB` = ?, `Competitor_Email` = ?, `Competitor_Description` = ?, `Competitor_Country` = ?, `Competitor_Gender` = ?, `Competitor_ContactNo` = ?, `Competitor_Website` = ?, `Competitor_Photo` = ? WHERE `Competitor_ID` = ?">
```

EDIT: Tried this code to get the Image's URL but I don't think I'm getting anything.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string imgPath = Path.Combine("~/UploadedFiles/", (GridView1.FindControl("gvImage")).ImageUrl); 
}
```

Comes up with 'Control' does not contain a definition for 'ImageUrl' and no extension method 'ImageUrl' accepting a first argument of type 'Control' could be found

Comment: what you did to find `gvImage`? Share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Image` is in a Control that repeats data, you have to specify the row number. `gvImage` only exists inside GridView1.

```
Image image = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("gvImage") as Image;
string imgPath = image.ImageUrl;
```